# How to explore microsoft/dotnet image based container folders?

Tags: docker, .net-core

I can explore files and folders in running container based on **alpine** image using following command:

> docker exec -it myimage sh

but how can I do this with running container basen on **microsoft/dotnet** (linux container) image? 
Obviously this image doesn't have **sh** tool. But it must have another one...

this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "xxx.dll"]
```

Comment: @KirkLarkin, bot *docker exec -i myimage /bin/bash* and *docker exec -i myimage bash* doesn't work

Comment: @KirkLarkin **docker exec -i myimage bash** worked actually! Thank you!

Comment: @KirkLarkin btw `-it` causing `the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'` error. `-i` worked